# How to figure out artifactSet to exclude in Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, jar

I have a java spark maven project. I am building an uber jar, this jar size is huge. I dont think I am using all of the dependencies it is packaging. My questions:

1. How do I find out the jars(dependencies) that are not used during compile/run?
2. How do I find out what is 'provided' vs the ones I need to package?
3. I see some poms having the following to do exactly that. How do I find out this list for my use case? Is this trial and error? Like I remove some, deploy and test? somehow even with a handful of entries in my pom, somehow maven has imported about 2000 jars. How do people find out the absolutely needed set of jars and keep the size to as minimum as possible?

```
<artifactSet>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on</exclude>
        <exclude>org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on</exclude>
        <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
        <exclude>com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:*</exclude>
            <exclude>javax.servlet:*</exclude>
        <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:*</exclude>
        <!-- Other long list of jars -->            
    </excludes>
</artifactSet>
```

Expected to build a small jar

Comment: Handful of entries in pom result in `somehow maven has imported about 2000 jars.` ?? Really ... can you show the pom file... ? Have you checked via `mvn dependency:analyze` etc.?

Comment: will add pom file shortly. Isnt dependency analyze only for compile time? How do I know if some jar is required for runtime? When I tried that and removed the jars and deployed to the server, it failed with ClassNotFound exceptions. How do people usually figure out if a jar is needed or not? Is it just manual from somehow knowing a jar is required?